# Run a process on a specific CPU

Tags: linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, cpu

**Problem**

I have a Soc containing let's say an Arm M7-core and an Arm A53-core, I want to only program the M7-core (Linux) and run a specific process on the A53-core.

**Questions**

- Is that possible or should I program both of them?
- I read about thread Affinity [in this article](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/c11-threads-affinity-and-hyperthreading/), and here I am not sure whether Affinity controls the running CPU in the Soc or the running core in the CPU (ARM cpu has several cores), please help.

Answer (score 1):

ARM big.LITTLE have three implementations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_big.LITTLE . On the first two implementations you can only select a cpu pair (with an Arm M7-core and an Arm A53-core) to run your thread. Depending on the workload, your threads will be executed in an M7 or A53.
Only in Heterogeneous Multi-Processing (HMP) implementation OS scheduler sees all  M7 and A53 cores and you can select a specific cpu type.

If the hardware has HMP, you can restrict your thread to a arbitrary set of cores using pthread_setaffinity_np ( https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setaffinity_np.3.html ). The cpu set macros (which manipulate core sets) identify cores by number, so you will have to discover which numbers are M7 or A53. Probably it is the same numbering in /proc/cpuinfo or /sys/devices/system/cpu/.

Comment: Ok, Nice to know so in case of ARM big.LITTLE Architecture, the cpu set really mean a set of cpus not only cpu cores otherwise it means core of the cpu right ?

Comment: Sorry, the system call and big.LITTLE use different naming and can become confusing together. pthread_setaffinity_np cpus sets are arbitrary core sets (actually sets of anything OS sees as a core, a hyperthread can appear as a core here), it doesn't care which cpu the core is or if there are cores with different architectures neither it doesn't know about big.LITTLE core sets.

You will just use it to restrict your process to specific cores. You have to find which cores are the ones you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run an application on a particular cpu, you can use `taskset`. For example, a Toradex Apalis iMX8, it has  2x Arm Cortex-A72, 4x Cortex-A53. To specify that an application just runs on the Cortex-A72s, use the command:

```bash
taskset -c 4,5 path_to_executable
```

Comment: Yup, and you'd look at `/proc/cpuinfo` to see which cores are which.